How to build and run a Angular Webapp
I have a problem. I need to build my angular application. I don’t mean just to start it. I mean to build it with ng build (in production) and then to start it to test it. It should be like a first release of the app.
The problem is: I built it, then the dist folder was created. In this folder I have browser and server. Now I read that I have to use http server. I did this, but when I connect with the http which is shown in the terminal I don’t see my Webapp. I just see a white screen with the dist folder and all the folders in it. All the files.
Why does this happen ? What did I wrong and what to do to fix this?
I also work with C# backend and this one manages all the data together with my database.
I read that my application has ssr activated. I don’t know if this is the problem.
I don’t know what to do. Could someone help me? It took all my energy for the day

To Build an Angular App you need to complete following requisitions..

NodeJs - Install latest node js Download and install from https://nodejs.org/en

Install angular CLI Command npm install -g @angular/cli

Open your editor and Run ng new my-angular-app from terminal

Run the App using command ng new my-angular-app ng serve (This will start a development server and compile the app)

To build the App Run Command ng build --prod


That's it. Done
Step To Run Your Production Build on local

Install http-server using command npm install -g http-server
Go to dist/your-angular-app folder in terminal
03.Now Run command http-server

Done. This will start a server on a default port like http://localhost:8080

At first. Thank you for you Answer. I did these steps and it compiled and also gave me this localhost address. The problem is I don’t see my application like in ng serve. Instead I just see the Dictionary dist and all the folders in it. It’s so confusing because I don’t know what I did wrong. And then there a errors like the polly, main.ts, html.index all of them not found, but actually this files are in it. I don’t understand what happens

Now I found a problem. I only get a index.csr.html in the dist folder. When I execute http-server than I only see index/of in my browser an all the folders. When I choose the index then nothing happens. White screen
